# Properties of independent and identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, iid

Do independent and identically distributed random variables always have the same expectation and variance?

Comment: Being `identically distributed` means they all have the `same` distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Being **identically distributed**  means they all have the same distribution, and, since expectation and variance can be calculated from the distribution, being functionals of the distribution, they must be the same.

By the way, independence plays no role here!

Comment: Not all probability distributions have defined expectations ([for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)), so your answer requires additional assumptions, right?